power bi date slicers with between as month /year
i have a table with dates values like ''1/1/2023 12:00:00 ''.
I wants a slicer with dates as for example 1/2023-5/2024.
i have a table with dates values like ''1/1/2023 12:00:00 ''.
I make a column as 1/2023 because my company wants a slicer with dates as for example 1/2023-5/2024.
but i see than if i put the column with values 1/2023 in slicers selection it doesnt exist the 'between ' only drop-down and other choise why?
i want a sicer with 1/2023-5/2024 not 1/1/2023-1/5/2024 how i can do it?
